# C# ASP.NET and MySql: How to wait until File.Exists?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, csv

I have an website `C# ASP.NET`, for create for the `*.csv` file from convert `*.xls` file in a chosen folder.

The app responsible for making that file takes following steps:

1. Make a *.csv file
2. Import the *.csv file in an dedicate table using LOAD DATA from MySQL

But there is a problem.

The LOAD DATA not find the *.csv file on the folder

> ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.51-community]File
> 'D:\inetpub\wwwroot\public\target_D8BD592B2F99_08-02-2022.csv' not
> found (Errcode: 2)

But the  *.csv file exists on the folder

> 'D:\inetpub\wwwroot\public\target_D8BD592B2F99_08-02-2022.csv'

I have tried without success waiting until `File.Exists`

Maybe the call of DATA LOAD is too fast?

Any suggestion?

```
var timeout = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

while (!File.Exists(output))
{
    if (DateTime.Now > timeout)
    {
        Response.Write("Application timeout; app_boxed could not be created; try again");
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    
    //LOAD DATA
}
```

Comment: Does the file exist on the machine MySQL is running?

Comment: Suppose the reason is in the lack of access right of MySql to the IIS folder. The file is exists but MySql can't get a write access.

Comment: @JesúsLópez Yes the file exists on the folder D:\inetpub\wwwroot\public\

Comment: @Kitta the .csv file is created in the folder D:\inetpub\wwwroot\public\ and exists

Comment: MySQL is running on the same machine as the web application?

Comment: Could you check an access right of NETWORK SERVICE (or other user that's run your MySQL service) to this folder. The user must have an write permissions

Comment: @JesúsLópez Yes the same machine

Comment: @Kitta I ask the server administrator thanks!

Comment: How is the file created in the first place? Why do you need to loop until it appears? If the file is created by your web app, you shouldn't have to guess whether it exists or not, unless there's a coding bug. As for `LOAD DATA`, you can use the MySqlBulkCopy class to bulk load the file instead of executing the raw command

Comment: @IterLsicIealf you didn't post the relevant code - the code that creates the file and the code that calls `LOAD DATA`. Perhaps you forgot to await an async method? Perhaps the path is wrong?

Comment: @IterLsicIealf storing uploaded files in `wwwroot` isn't a good idea either. On one hand, files under that folder are meant to be content server to clients. On the other hand, only the web app application pool account has permission to that folder.  [MySqlBulkCopy](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbulkcopytype/) can avoid this and even send data directly from the Excel files. If you use ExcelDataReader, you cap pass the loaded data directly to `WriteToServerAsync`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the *real* problem is how to import Excel files into MySQL. This can be done without converting the files to CSV or calling `LOAD DATA` explicitly.

Bulk loading data into MySql can be done using the [MySqlBulkCopy](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbulkcopytype/) class from the open source [MySqlConnector.NET](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) library.

MySqlConnector can send any data stored in a DataTable or available through an IDbDataReader interface to MySQL, using `LOAD DATA` underneath. This means all we need is a way to get an IDbDataReader from an Excel file.

```
using var excelReader = GetReaderFromExcel(somePath);

// open the connection
using var connection = new MySqlConnection("...;AllowLoadLocalInfile=True");
await connection.OpenAsync();

// bulk copy the data
var bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(connection);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "some_table_name";
var result = await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable);

// check for problems
if (result.Warnings.Count != 0) { /* handle potential data loss warnings */ }
```

The popular [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) can read data from `xlsx` or the obsolete `xls` format and return an `IDbDataReader`, without having to install OLEDB drivers. Reading data from an Excel file can be done with 2 lines.

```
using var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);
...
```

Putting it all together :

```
using var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
using var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);

using var connection = new MySqlConnection("...;AllowLoadLocalInfile=True");
await connection.OpenAsync();

var bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(connection);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "some_table_name";
var result = await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable);

if (result.Warnings.Count != 0) { /* handle potential data loss warnings */ }
```